# Question about an inverse limit.

Tags: abstract-algebra, limits-colimits

Define a partial order on $\Bbb{N}$ to be $n \leq m$ iff $n = m $ or $n |m$ and there's a twin prime dividing $m$ and not $n$.  It's easy to see that it's a poset.  Define a system of abelian groups $A_n = \Bbb{Z}/n$ with $p_{nm} : A_m \to A_n$ the natural projections.  Clearly $p_{ii} = \text{id}$.  And if $i \leq j \leq k$, $p_{ik} = p_{ij} \circ p_{jk}$  So take the inverse limit and call it $A$.    Consider the inverse system in which $n \leq m$ iff $n | m$ with the usual projections and call it $B$.  Then is $A$ a just a subring of $B$ or is it an ideal?

Comment: Do you really think $A$ is smaller than $B$?

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I'm not sure what they look like.

Comment: What do you know about inverse limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that both systems in question consist of the same set of abelian groups. The only difference is that the system defining $A$ has *less arrows* in it. It follows that there is a natural inclusion $B\hookrightarrow A$ (and not vice versa). By definition, $B$ and $A$ are rings, and under this embedding we may say that $B$ is a subring of $A$.